I'm trying to let pandas turn numpy arrays to an excel file, but my CPU gave me an error. Here's my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "a": np.array([1, 4, 6]),
  "b": np.array([6, 9, 2])
}
data["c"] = data["a"] + data["b"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel("C:\Users\TeamWagner\Documents\db.xlsx", index=False)

print(df.head())

I tried setting the data "c" key to dats "a" + data "b".  I expected "c" to equal [7, 13, 8] in the excel file, but it threw me an error instead.

Post the error. That code works fine. It must be a file path problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you get an error, please post it too (as text)

Here is what you should do:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "a": np.array([1, 4, 6]),
  "b": np.array([6, 9, 2])
}
data["c"] = data["a"] + data["b"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel(r"C:******\db.xlsx", index=False) 

print(df.head())

What changed?

df.to_excel("C:******\db.xlsx", index=False)


changed to

df.to_excel(r"C:******\db.xlsx", index=False)

This gives you
   a  b   c
0  1  6   7
1  4  9  13
2  6  2   8

